# If statement not being evaluated C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a function to return the difference between two dates. So, for the yearsDifference statement (see breakpoint comment in the code), I'm subtracting one from the other and then use an if statement to check if the result is negative.

The if statement does not getting evaluated, what is causing this?

I've used a breakpoint in visual studio to check it line-by-line, and it does not stop on the if statement to be able to check it.

```
int UUDate::Between(UUDate date) {
//TODO - Add your implementation here
int daycount = 0;
int tempMonth = date.month_;
int tempDay = date.day_;
int yearDifference;

while (month_ != tempMonth)
{
    if (month_ == 1 || month_ == 3 || month_ == 5 || month_ == 7 || month_ == 8 || month_ == 10 || month_ == 12) {
        daycount += 31;
    }
    else if (month_ != 2) {
        daycount += 30;
    }
    else {
        if (year_ % 4 == 0) {
            daycount += 29;
        }
        else {
            daycount += 28;
        }
    }
    tempMonth++;
    if (tempMonth > 12)
        tempMonth = 1;
}

yearDifference = year_ - date.year_; //breakpoint here
if (yearDifference < 0) { //skipped
    yearDifference * -1;
}
if (day_ - tempDay < 0) {
    return ((day_ - tempDay) * 1) + daycount + (yearDifference * 365);
}
else {
    return (day_ - tempDay) + daycount + (yearDifference * 365);
}
```

}

Comment: What are the values of `year_` and `date.year`?  Also, what are their types?

Comment: year_ is 2000 and date.year is 2002 resulting in -2

Comment: Just to be sure, you are debugging/stepping through a debug build, not a release build, correct?

Comment: @pstrjds correct

Comment: @Minimarshman What are the types of `year_` and `date.year`?

Comment: @Minimarshman Would you mind to provide a [MCVE] demonstrating your problem as required here please.

Comment: can we see UUDate please

Comment: Unrelated, but that whole while loop thing you got going on there is extremely confusing.  From what I can see `month_` is global/class member variable, and is not changing with each loop iteration, yet you are performing a bunch of comparisons with it to increase your day count. I feel like those if statements should be checking the value of `tempMonth` - not sure, I could be wrong, but it sure feels incorrect. For example, if `month_` is 12 and `tempMonth` is starting at 1, you are going to add 31 day 11 times, but, if I am understanding your goal, that is incorrect.

Comment: @pstrjds probably confusing but it returns the correct date just negative due to the issues been shown

Comment: @NathanOliver both ints

Comment: I see a Y2100 problem brewing here...

Comment: What type is `year_`? What was the value of `yearDifference` when you stopped at the breakpoint?

Comment: @Minimarshman - Are you absolutely positive about that? I just read it again. I am assuming the while loop is computing the number of days between the two months (in the sense of number of days between the month January and December). Using that example, with `month_` being December (12), then you are going to loop with `tempMonth` being 1 and will add 31 to the day count, then `tempMonth` is set to 2 and loops again, and again you add 31, but probably should be adding 28/29, and so on. That loop could be replaced with a couple of if statements and a multiplication.

Comment: @Minimarshman - Another unrelated issue is you are ignoring leap years that occur between dates if they are from different years.  You are only adding 365 days for each year difference, but if the number of years between the two dates is over 4, there is a good chance that a leap year has occurred which contained 366 days.  I don't know how exact you need to be, so maybe that is okay, but just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (yearDifference < 0) { //skipped
    yearDifference * -1;
}
```

This code doesn't do anything. Multiplying `yearDifference` by `-1` and throwing the result away has no effect. You probably meant `yearDifference *= -1;` which is equivalent to `yearDifference = yearDifference * -1;`.

Comment: I just posted the same solution half a second after you but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution it was a simple mistake and i didnt realise it prevented the if statement from being evaluated. 
In the if statement i had

```
yeardifference * -1;
```

Which is a typo its supposed to have an equals after the asterisk to multiply yearDiffernce by -1 so as to turn it from negative to positive. Sorry everyone made a simple mistake although thanks for your help :)

Comment: For the future, add logging to your code when you have a problem like this. Log the value of `yearDifference` before the `if`. Log entry to the conditional block. Maybe even add an `else` block with a log entry "we took the else block", and so on. This will help you figure things like this out.

Comment: It doesn't "prevent the if statement from evaluating" but a debugger never stops on a conditional (or does it?) so yours has nothing to do.

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised if the compiler didn't give a warning about this. All of MSVC, GCC, and Clang warn when you have a statement like this that doesn't do anything. A quick test on Compiler Explorer gave me a warning from MSVC without even adding any warning options.